# How wait for alert box to perform the action in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am pressing a cancel button than according to my code it is checking some text.  In Chrome and Firefox it is working fine but in IE it is taking time to perform operation on alert box but code moves to next line.

So i want some code that stop till the operation is preformed on alert box and than it goes to next Step.  I am doing automation testing using selenium.

Please find piece of code:

```
Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();
al.accept();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-body-full']/p[1]")));
assertEquals("Your cancellation request has been successfully executed.",driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-body-full']/p[1]")).getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 16):

You want to wait until the alert is present before switching to it, similar to your 3rd row. [Reference.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent%28%29)

EDIT: try:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        .ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();
al.accept();
```

Comment: In this code first line is switching to alert box and second line is pressing ok button.  Than it is checking some element.                                                               I want that it must move to next line only and only if ok button of alert is pressed

Comment: Do you have any idea about this                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053632/is-xpath-is-different-for-different-browser

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Local variable for alert seems redundant - instead:  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();