# Why do the xpath locators differ for chrome and firefox/firebug in Selenium test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

in chrome I get a xpath value:
`//*[@id='user_change_pw_form']/div[3]/span`

and for the same element in firebug I get:
`/html/body/div[2]/form/div[3]/span`

why do I have to speparate the xpath queries like that to get one and the same element in Selenium testcase:

```
switch (System.getProperty("test.driver")) 
        {
            case "chrome":
            case "html":
                text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_change_pw_form']/div[3]/span")).getText();


            case "gecko":
                text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div[3]/span")).getText(); 
                break;

        }
```

While the respective counterpart gives for the wrong browser "Unable to locate element", though both xpath queries work in both browser consoles.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053632/is-xpath-is-different-for-different-browser

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firefox has absolute xpath and cannot handle chrome's xpath.

Thanks to @noor and @Kenil Fadia

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your own xPaths / CSS selectors rather than relying on browser based selectors. This [link](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) would help you learn/write your own selectors.

I would also suggest using css selectors over xpaths since they are more readable.