# cssSelector vs XPath for selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

As per my understanding, CSS selector traverses through the DOM. Because CSS files will not have any info about element position then why *cssSelector* is faster then *XPath* (theoretically).

Theoretically *cssSelector* taking less time then *XPath* as *XPath* need to traverse through HTML DOM.
*XPath* we can search elements backward or forward in the DOM hierarchy while *CSS* works only in a forward direction.

But if *cssSelector* also traverse through HTML DOM then how it make *cssSelector* faster.

In other words how *cssSelector* actually works internally and reason why it always preferable/recommended to use by everyone then *xpath*

Also please share other benefit of using *cssSelector* over *XPath*.

And vice versa in which area *XPath* are better then *cssSelector*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between css-selector & Xpath? which is better(according to performance & for cross browser testing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t)

Comment: @Andersson That Q is pretty old and the answer isn't really that accurate. The XPath *and* CSS selector engines are different in each browser so that doesn't make them inconsistent or slower on either side. XPath being hard to read isn't a performance issue.

Answer (score 9):

I've read a lot of articles and I've seen some like [this](https://saucelabs.com/blog/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath) and [this](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css) that have data that show that CSS selectors are faster and I've done a little testing and have come to the same conclusion. I talked to Dave Haeffner, author of elementalselenium.com, in Dec 2016 and asked him about the perf numbers on his site (in the post I linked above) since they were pretty old. He [linked me a presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b6nztwjra8jm6y/selenium-grading.pdf?dl=0) (see pp18-23) where he updated the tests and CSS selectors are still faster but XPath is catching up in a few configs.

So we can see evidence that it's true but I've never seen anyone talk about the technical details of *why*. If I were to guess, it would be because a lot of work has gone into the different browsers to optimize the speed of page rendering. Having CSS selectors work quickly makes the page render faster and since the browser drivers take advantage of the browser's ability to locate elements, that means CSS selectors generally win. I've read that some browsers have improved their XPath locator speed but I think it will likely always lag behind CSS selectors because it's just much less common than CSS selectors.

Both CSS selectors and XPath have to traverse through the DOM so there's no real difference there other than the speed of the engine that does the traversing. The CSS selector engine is likely a fine tuned machine by this point vs the XPath engine because of the wide spread use of CSS selectors.

My general locator strategy is ID first, CSS selector for everything else. When nothing else works I use XPath. It will vary from site to site but in my experience, IDs are maybe ~10% of my locators. CSS selectors are probably ~80% and the last 10% is XPath. I generally use XPath for when I need to locate an element by the contained text and very rarely DOM traversal. An example of my XPath usage might be I need to find an element in a TABLE relative to a row label, e.g. the price of cheese in a table row where the first cell contains "cheese" and the third cell contains the price.

I think XPath is seen a lot on sites like SO and many blogs because of its easy access. All I have to do is right-click an element in the devtools and Copy XPath. The problem is many times that generates a bad, brittle XPath. A handcrafted XPath is better but it takes time and experience to handcraft a good XPath or CSS selector. Time that many aren't willing to put in. A badly crafted CSS selector or XPath will make things slower also. Many times there are any number of ways that an element could be located, some are way more efficient than others... it comes down to the efficiency of the locator and how you use it. A badly formed CSS selector isn't automatically going to be faster than a well formed XPath,.

Comment: thanks @JeffC .. it was a pretty good explanation. I have got to know many thing. For now I am keeping this question open and waiting for any tech explanation. will approve the answer according .. voting you up for now. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

The debate between *cssSelector* vs *XPath* still now remains as one of the most heated and subjective conversation in the *Selenium Community*. A quick recap on what we had already known so far can be summarized as:

- People in favor of *cssSelector* say that it is more readable and faster (specifically when running against Internet Explorer).
- While those in favor of *XPath* tout it's ability to transverse the page (while *cssSelector* cannot).
- Traversing the DOM in older browsers like IE8 does not work with *cssSelector* but is fine with *XPath*.
- *XPath* can walk up the DOM (e.g. from child to parent), whereas *cssSelector* can only traverse down the DOM (e.g. from parent to child)
- However not being able to traverse the DOM with *cssSelector* in older browsers isn't necessarily a bad thing as it is more of an indicator that your page has poor design and could benefit from some helpful markup.

*Dave Haeffner* carried out a [*test*](https://gist.github.com/tourdedave/8309313) on [*a page with two HTML data tables*](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables), one table is written without helpful attributes (*ID* and *Class*), and the other with them. I have analyzed the *test procedure* and the outcome of this experiment in details in the discussion [Why should I ever use CSS selectors as opposed to XPath for automated testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936193/why-should-i-ever-use-css-selectors-as-opposed-to-xpath-for-automated-testing/51942615#51942615). While this experiment demonstrated that each [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) is reasonably equivalent across browsers, it didn't adequately paint the whole picture for us.

---

### cssSelector vs XPath, Under a Microscope

*Dave Haeffner* in the discussion [Css Vs. X Path, Under a Microscope](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/33-xpath-vs-css-revisited) mentioned, in an an end-to-end test there were a lot of other variables at play *Sauce startup*, *Browser start up*, and *latency* to and from the application under test. The unfortunate takeaway from that experiment could be that one driver may be faster than the other (e.g. *IE* vs *Firefox*), when in fact, that's wasn't the case at all. To get a real taste of what the performance difference is between *cssSelector* and *XPath*, we need to dig deeper. This can be achieved by running everything from a local machine while using a performance bench-marking utility. The focus was on a specific Selenium action rather than the entire test run, and run things numerous times.

To demonstrate this detailed example, a Windows XP virtual machine was setup and [Ruby (1.9.3)](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) was installed. All the available browsers and their equivalent browser drivers for Selenium was also installed. For bench-marking, Ruby's standard lib [**`benchmark`**](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2013/06/19/how-do-i-benchmark-ruby-code/) was used.

---

### The Test

In order to get an adequate sample set of data, the same test was ran against each browser 100 times. And to weed out anomalies in the data the rehearsal feature of benchmark was used so that it would run the *full test sequence*, *perform garbage collection*, and then run it again. To make things comparable, a few of the locators were updated to make for better matches in comparison to each other. And the specific action we measured is **`find_element`**.

---

### Test Code

```
require_relative 'base'
require 'benchmark'

class SmallDOM < Base

  LOCATORS = {
    :id => {
      id: 'table2'
    },
    :table_header_class => {
      class: 'dues'
    },
    :table_header_id_and_class => {
      :css => "#table2 thead .dues",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']//thead//*[@class='dues']"
    },
    :table_header_id_class_and_direct_desc => {
      :css => "#table2 > thead .dues",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']/thead//*[@class='dues']"
    },
    :table_header_traversing => {
      :css => "#table2 thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']//thead//tr//th[4]"
    },
    :table_header_traversing_and_direct_desc => {
      :css => "#table2 > thead > tr > th:nth-of-type(4)",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']/thead/tr/th[4]"
    },
    :table_cell_id_and_class => {
      :css => "#table2 tbody .dues",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']//tbody//*[@class='dues']"
    },
    :table_cell_id_class_and_direct_desc => {
      :css => "#table2 > tbody .dues",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']/tbody//*[@class='dues']"
    },
    :table_cell_traversing => {
      :css => "#table2 tbody tr td:nth-of-type(4)",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']//tbody//tr//td[4]"
    },
    :table_cell_traversing_and_direct_desc => {
      :css => "#table2 > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(4)",
      :xpath => "//table[@id='table2']/tbody/tr/td[4]"
    }
  }

  attr_reader :driver

  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
    visit '/tables'
    super
  end

  # The benchmarking approach was borrowed from
  # http://rubylearning.com/blog/2013/06/19/how-do-i-benchmark-ruby-code/
  def benchmark
    Benchmark.bmbm(27) do |bm|
      LOCATORS.each do |example, data|
    data.each do |strategy, locator|
      bm.report(example.to_s + " using " + strategy.to_s) do
        begin
          ENV['iterations'].to_i.times do
         find(strategy => locator)
          end
        rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
          puts "( 0.0 )"
        end
      end
    end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

### Results

> **NOTE**: The output is in seconds, and the results are for the total run time of 100 executions.

[image: css_xpath_under_microscope]

---

### Analyzing the Results

- On a whole, Internet Explorer is slower than the other drivers, but between CSS and XPath it looks like XPath is actually faster than CSS.
- Chrome and Opera have some differences, albeit much smaller, but they sway in both directions.
- In some cases CSS is faster, and in others, XPath.
- Firefox looks to be a bit more optimized for CSS since it's mostly faster across the board.

---

### Outro

Even with these speed differences they are only a few seconds (or fractions of seconds) apart -- and that's for 100 executions. When you think about how it takes 30 seconds or more to complete a test run, this kind of difference is negligible. So, the choice between [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) can be a tough one to make. But now you are armed with more than enough data to make the choice for yourself. It's really just a matter of finding what works for you and your team and to not get weighed down by the hype and opinions around which one is better.

Answer (score -1):

I always use xpath. With xpath I've got the ability to use any of the attributes of an object, including it's ID or Name. I can use combinations and subsets of them and invoke xpath's powerful language if I need it.

From my experience, navigating the DOM tree using xpath is a better way of locating an object than using CSS which is after all meant to describe only how it is displayed.

As for speed comparison, I'd reckon it would depend on the complexity of the expression. Does `find_element_by_id('myID')` or `find_element_by_xpath(@id='myID')` or `find_element_by_css_selector ('myID')` invoke different engines and produce different response times?

Much of the bad press I've heard and read about xpath is because people use hardcoded paths like `//div[1]/div[2]/a[3]` which is brittle. A more robust xpath expression like `//div[@id='main']//a[@href='xpath_nodes.asp']` could be written.

Comment: If you already have an id then why would you want to go with xpath ?

Comment: @cruisepandy - I like to stick with xpath for consistency. The id is just another attribute of the object.

Comment: XPath and CSS do use different locating engines in the browsers. CSS is more widely and consistently supported and it's also faster and the syntax is simpler. I do use XPath but only for times when I need to find an element by contained text or for DOM traversal... but that's it.

Comment: Here's a quick reference for those that come later... http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2

Comment: I perfer xpath also, you can find anything css can find in xpath,plus some. My code base is thus more consistent. Also, the XPath syntax look simple and straightforward enough for me.  A few milli seconds of css speed edge does not matter to me. In real world web app, at least those I have worked with, not everyone is so nice as to put a unique id to all the elements you want to point and click on.