# Azure DevOps VSTest (Selenium) timeout task failed

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, specflow, xunit.net

```
**************** Starting test execution *********************
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\VsTest\16.4.0\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@d:\a\_temp\ob3w54ta3i1.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.4.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "d:\a\1\s\site\tests\WebSite.Automacao.Tests\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp3.1\WebSite.Automacao.Tests.dll"
/Settings:"d:\a\_temp\bvgizjzmqi2.tmp.runsettings"
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"d:\a\1\s"
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 3.1.5)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.73]   Discovering: WebSite.Automacao.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.89]   Discovered:  WebSite.Automacao.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.89]   Starting:    WebSite.Automacao.Tests
-> Loading plugin d:\a\1\s\site\tests\WebSite.Automacao.Tests\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecFlow.xUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
-> Using default config
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 50056
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 50059
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 50058
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 50057
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
##[error][xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]     
Register a new address [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]       OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 300 seconds: Timeout expired on selector By.LinkText: Register
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]            at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.38]         d:\a\1\s\site\tests\WebSite.Automacao.Tests\Config\WebDriverExtensions.cs(22,0): at WebSite.Automacao.Tests.Config.WebDriverExtensions.FindDelay(IWebDriver driver, By by, Int32 timeoutInSeconds, Int32 waitTimeInMilliseconds)
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.39]         d:\a\1\s\site\tests\WebSite.Automacao.Tests\Config\WebDriverExtensions.cs(45,0): at WebSite.Automacao.Tests.Config.WebDriverExtensions.DelayClick(IWebDriver driver, By by, Int32 timeoutInSeconds, Int32 waitTimeInMilliseconds)
[xUnit.net 00:05:23.39]         d:\a\1\s\site\tests\WebSite.Automacao.Tests\Config\SeleniumHelper.cs(44,0): at WebSite.Automacao.Tests.Config.SeleniumHelper.ClickLinkByText(String linkText)
```

> Project: .NET Core 3.1

> References:

```
    <PackageReference Include="bogus" Version="29.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="83.0.4103.3910" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver" Version="0.26.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.3.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.3.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.3.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.2">
```

**Browsers and webdrivers** 
Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106 
Chrome Driver 83.0.4103.39

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

The tests access an externally published url.
For example: https://stackoverflow.com/

I increased the timeout to 300 seconds but was unsuccessful.

All tests run successfully in Visual Studio 2019.

> ***Edited***

Checking the test prints, it was found that the problem is in the resolution that opens the browser.

```
IWebDriver webDriver = null;
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--no-first-run");
options.AddArgument("--no-default-browser-check");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
webDriver.Manage().Window.FullScreen();
```

> Retrieving the screen size

```
webDriver.Manage().Window.Size
```

window-size: {Width=1024, Height=768}

***How to change the screen resolution in AzureDevOps?***

Comment: Could you translate the error message to English? We cannot help you unless we know the error message, and unfortunately we are mostly English speakers on StackOverflow.

Comment: @GregBurghardt sorry... edited

Comment: From the error log, this issue is on the `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register"))` calls. Check if [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190909/random-selenium-e2e-tests-fail-because-of-timeouts-on-azure-devops-but-work-loca) could give you some ideas.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the C# code, as well as the relevant HTML.

Comment: @GregBurghardt 
I made the edit after checking the problem with the screen resolution

Comment: I'm confused. The error in the test output is "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 300 seconds: Timeout expired on selector By.LinkText: Register" which implies it failed to find an element by link text. What does this have to do with resizing the browser window?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I included this task in my build definition and apparently I solved the problem.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task

Comment: That's really good to know. Running SpecFlow tests with Selenium in DevOps has been on my to-do list for a while. It would be worth while to post an answer to your own question explaining the root cause of the problem, and including a link to the build task.