# How to get past popups and continue to login using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been able to get past the pop up in my code but I am not able to then type in the email and password for the account via sending the keys and then hit the login button.

Here is the code I am using and the site I am trying to login to. I am VERY new so any response please try to explain so I am able to learn from my mistakes.

Thanks so much in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

PATH = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051")


main_page = driver.current_window_handle
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "at least 21 years old.")]').click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "at least 21 years old.")]/span').click()

for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle != main_page:
        login_page = handle
driver.switch_to.window(login_page)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "at least 21 years old.")]').click()
driver.switch_to.window(main_page)

WebDriverWait(driver,1)

fwgsUsername = credentials.login['candmidlik@yahoo.com']
fwgsPassword = credentials.login['Password2']
emailFieldID     = "logonId"
passFieldID      = "logonPassword"
loginButtonXpath = "//input[@id = 'loginButton']"

emailFieldElement   = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(emailFieldID))
emailFieldElement.clear()
emailFieldElement.send_keys(fwgsUsername)

passFieldElement    = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda     driver: driver.find_element_by_name(passFieldID))
passFieldElement.clear()
passFieldElement.send_keys(fwgsPassword)

logInButtonElement  = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
logInButtonElement.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the *E-mail* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='YES']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.emailInput_myacc[name='logonId']"))).send_keys("Candcrush@Candcrush.Candcrush")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.emailInput_myacc[name='logonPassword']").send_keys("Candcrush")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#loginButton").click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='YES']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='emailInput_myacc' and @name='logonId']"))).send_keys("Candcrush@Candcrush.Candcrush")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='emailInput_myacc' and @name='logonPassword']").send_keys("Candcrush")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='loginButton']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: CandyCrush]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Which is better use css selector or xpath?

Comment: @Candcrush Of coarse [_**CssSelector**_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936193/why-should-i-ever-use-css-selectors-as-opposed-to-xpath-for-automated-testing/51942615#51942615)

Answer (score 0):

You should swap over to webdriver wait for the yes since it's not switching windows. Also your xpath for the login was an a tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get("https://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LogonForm?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10051")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[.="YES"]'))).click()


fwgsUsername = 'candmidlik@yahoo.com'
fwgsPassword = 'Icecream90'
emailFieldID     = "logonId"
passFieldID      = "logonPassword"
loginButtonXpath = "//a[@id = 'loginButton']"

emailFieldElement   = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(emailFieldID))
emailFieldElement.clear()
emailFieldElement.send_keys(fwgsUsername)

passFieldElement    = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda  driver: driver.find_element_by_name(passFieldID))
passFieldElement.clear()
passFieldElement.send_keys(fwgsPassword)

logInButtonElement  = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
logInButtonElement.click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```