# XPath for element by attribute value in Selenium?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

For the following HTML:

[image]

Why does the following XPath doesn't work:

```
//option[value='0']
```

Is it related to `value` or to `option` element?

Comment: Next time, please post text, formatted as code, not an image of your markup.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
//option[value='0']
```

to

```
//option[@value='0']
```

because `value` is an attribute, not an element.

Answer (score 3):

```
//option[value='0']
```

is not a valid selector incase you are attempting to identify/select the respective `<option>` element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447).

---

### Solution

You can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //option[@value='0']
  ```
- *css_selector*:

  ```
  option[value='0']
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Why should I ever use CSS selectors as opposed to XPath for automated testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942615/7429447)

Comment: Nice answer.  Readers shouldn't miss the excellent supporting links too.

Answer (score 1):

Your current xpath is searching for an `option` element with a child *element* `value` which in turn has *contents* `0`. What you actually want to find is an `option` element with an *attribute* `value` with value `0`:

```
//option[@value='0']
```

Comment: I thought that in order to search for a child i should use **/**

Comment: @Eitanos30:  AakashM (+1) (and all answerers, in fact) have explained that `value` selects a child ***element***; `@value` selects an ***attribute***.   Your markup has `value` as an attribute, so use `@`.