# Chrome & Firefox on Windows vs Linux (selenium)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker, firefox, selenium-grid

I'm running Selenium grid with only Windows machines and the resource use is quite high.

I've been toying with the idea of putting Chrome and Firefox inside docker containers to improve efficiency.

My question is are there any key differences in the browsers themselves on the different platforms, i.e. would Chrome on Windows behave differently to Chrome on Linux or do they run the same code and behave the same?

Comment: Hello I’m facing the same situation. Have you switched to Linux container? How it’s going? Have you found any discrepancy between windows and linux?

Comment: @gary.zhangyes we are in the process of switching to Docker and have found it much easier to manage browser versioning and server performance. We took the decision to presume there is no difference in the platform and we've not seen an issue in docker that we couldn't replicate on windows. It's worth noting however that docker only supports Chrome/Firefox so if you want to test IE/Edge you will need the existing infrastructure or cloud-based alternative, we're running a hybrid system.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) tends to mock the *User Actions* and some among them are:

- Sending Text : `sendKeys("LiamHarries")`
- Special Keyboard Characters : `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` and `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)`
- Mouse Hover : `moveToElement(element).perform()`
- Click : `click()`

All these *User Actions* are independent of the underlying [os](/questions/tagged/os) and *Hardware Configuration*. Hence if they run the same code and they will behave the same.

---

### Update :

As per your comment *...if something is rendered one was on chrome on windows will it be the same on chrome on Linux...*, it is worth to mention when new versions of Web Browsers are published in different formats (e.g. `.tz`/`.tr`/`.gz` for `Linux` and `.zip`/`.rar` for `Windows`) and they contain the required components (separate for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) / [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) and `32` / `64` bit) to install the Browser as per underlying OS Architecture.

Though the *install location* and *directory structure* may vary within the [os](/questions/tagged/os) , the release candidate [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) goes through different *Testing Procedures* (e.g. *Alpha Testing*, *Beta Testing*, *UAT* and *UX Control Testing*) which does ensures that the *User Experience* is seamless and similar across all OS Variants.

Hence, from *Selenium*'s perspective underlying hardware bears **no impact**

> **Note** : There have been instances when the *Headless Chrome* feature was available in early *Google Chrome* builds but that was a well planned move following the *Chrome Release Map*

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I was more interested in the browsers themselves than selenium. for example if something is rendered one was on chrome on windows will it be the same on chrome on Linux.

The vast majority of our customers use windows however the efficiency savings of Linux is high that if there are no major differences then testing on Linux rather than windows will be an acceptable risk.

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know if any counter questions.