# ChromeDriver is too slower than GeckoDriver on the first page query through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, google-chrome-headless

I have the latest version of the drivers (chromedriver=2.44.609551), selenium package(3.141.0) and the (headless chrome=70.0.3538.110). (on windows)

I am opening multiple windows with the browser.
Using firefox, my script is always fast. But on chrome, after switching to a window (with the page already loaded), when I try to get anything from the browser (like driver.page_source or any find_element), I get a 4s-ish delay.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
[driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', url) for url in urls]
for window in driver.window_handles[1:]:
    driver.switch_to.window(window)
    driver.page_source                                #it takes 4s here
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class_name')  #regular speed here (fast)
    break
```

If i switch `driver.page_source` with `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class_name')`, the first one will be always slow.

Comment: What your script does?

Comment: @aliusman, just edited with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox* combination is faster then *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* at this point it is worth to mention that diferent browsers render the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in a different way.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Chrome & Firefox on Windows vs Linux (selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939389/chrome-firefox-on-windows-vs-linux-selenium/47939721#47939721)

Moreover, there had been a lot of discussion going around about the unpredictable *CPU* and *Memory Consumption* by **Chrome Headless** sessions.

As per the discussion [Building headless for minimum cpu+mem usage](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/f_tQUs__Yqw) the CPU + Memory usage can be optimized by:

- Using either a custom proxy or C++ ProtocolHandlers you could return stub 1x1 pixel images or even block them entirely.
- Chromium Team is working on adding a [programmatic control](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646774) over when frames are produced. Currently headless chrome is still trying to render at **60 fps** which is rather wasteful. Many pages do need a few frames (maybe **10-20 fps**) to render properly (due to usage of `requestAnimationFrame` and `animation triggers`) but we expect there are a lot of CPU savings to be had here.
- [**MemoryInfra**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/memory-infra/) should help you determine which component is the biggest consumer of memory in your setup.
- An usage can be:

  ```
  $ headless_shell --remote-debugging-port=9222 --trace-startup=*,disabled-by-default-memory-infra http://www.chromium.org
  ```
- Chromium is always going to use as much resources as are available to it. If you want to effectively limit it's utilization, you should look into using [cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01)

You can find a detailed discussion in [Limit chrome headless CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage)