# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: GET /session/.../window/rect did not match a known command with get_window_position()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, webdriver-w3c-spec

When I run this code

```
url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.get_window_position())'
```

I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: GET /session/bbb48fc8-51ba-4cff-b639-771f80489785/window/rect did not match a known command
```

The error seems to be in the `get_window_position()` method. Any idea?

Comment: Usually things like ` did not match a known command` is because of a mismatch between Selenium/webdriver/browser versions. Be sure to update to latest version of selnium, geckodriver, and Firefox. Please update with the versions you're using.

Comment: It worked for me on my local machine. I think yours selenium needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: GET /session/bbb48fc8-51ba-4cff-b639-771f80489785/window/rect did not match a known command
```

...implies that the **GET** method on the **/session/{session id}/window/rect** *endpoint* i.e. [Get Window Rect](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-get-window-rect) **failed**.

---

### get_window_position

[get_window_position()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_window_position) gets the x,y position of the current window.

- Usage:

  ```
  driver.get_window_position()
  ```

> **Note**: Supported for W3C compatibile browsers.

I have used your own code at on my *Windows 8* box as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.get_window_position())
```

But unable to reproduce the error/issue.

---

However at this point it is worth to mention that *different Browser Clients renders the HTML in a different way*. You can find a relevant discussion in [Chrome & Firefox on Windows vs Linux (selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939389/chrome-firefox-on-windows-vs-linux-selenium/47939721#47939721).

It is possible as per your *Test Configuration* the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) returned back the control to the *WebDriver* instance i.e. **'document.readyState' equal to "complete"** before the `/session/{session id}/window/rect` *endpoint*  was established.

### Solution

Induce *WebDriverWait* before you try to extract the **window_position** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  url = 'https://www.google.com'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Google"))
  print(driver.get_window_position())
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  {'x': -8, 'y': -8}
  ```