# getTitle() method returns title of current page with Chrome but returns title of previous page with Firefox using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, webdriverwait

I Need to verify title of a webpage after login is done. Using the Chrome Driver for selenium the title of page after login is coming correct but not firefox driver. Rest of the code remains same, just the driver was changed from chrome to firefox.

```
public void verifyLoginPage()
{
    String homepage= "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage";

    if (driver.getTitle().equals(homepage))
    {
        System.out.println("Its the correct Homepage after Login");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Page after login is not the intended one");
    }
}
```

With Chrome driver this code returns " Its the correct Homepage after Login" and with firefox driver this code returns " Page after login is not the intended one" , as getTitle returns the title of login page, not after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browser renders the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in a different way. You can find a relevant discussion in [Chrome & Firefox on Windows vs Linux (selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939389/chrome-firefox-on-windows-vs-linux-selenium/47939721#47939721). At this point it is worth to be mentioned that:

- *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* is based on **OSS** dialect.
- *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox* is based on **W3C** dialect.

It seems in your *usecase*:

- While using *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome*, the *Page Title* is already  rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) by the time **`document.readyState`** *equals to* **`complete`** is attained.
- But while using *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox*, the *Page Title* is **not**  rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) by the time **`document.readyState`** *equals to* **`complete`** is attained.

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *title to contain* and you can use the following solution:

```
public void verifyLoginPage()
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Guru99");
    String homepage= "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage";
    if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(homepage))
        System.out.println("Its the correct Homepage after Login");
    else
        System.out.println("Page after login is not the intended one");
}
```

Comment: I had initially tried implicit wait of 20 seconds, but was not working. With explicit wait from your suggestion (20s), first time it worked and failed second time. After i have increased explicit wait for 40s, its behaving as expected in all runs.         Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***Can you please try to execute below code and let's know if it worked.***

*Once you have opened chrome or Firefox driver, after that please add below code and see -*

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10
driver.navigate().to("http://sitename.com");
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String expectedTitle = "page title to be verified";
if(actualTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedTitle))
System.out.println("Title Matched");
else
System.out.println("Title didn't match");
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: The porblem is i cannot specify static url here in code  i.e driver.navigate().to("http://sitename.com");", it should come from driver.getcurrenturl() afterlogin is done. which work fine in chrome. I tried adding your suggestion with " driver.navigate().to(driver.getCurrentUrl());" , but again it works in chrome only. :(

Comment: Does not Firefox return same url as u get in chrome using driver.getcurrenturl()

Comment: with driver.getcurrenturl(), the value is different in both chrome and firefox. Although login is happening correctly with firefox as well. But somehow the latest page title is not retrieved.  to be more clear, Below is what i am doing:                                    1. Initialize driver chrome or firefox.  2. Login to base url 3. validate the title of url after login.  so with firefox login happens but the gettitle() or getcurrenturl() gives data of previous page.