# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message error sending text to username field within iframe using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

When i try to locate one element with selellium it fails

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://eltiempo.com/login")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username']"))
    )

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Any reason for using XPATH over id selector?. Please try with id selector, id is unique in entire DOM and id selector works much better than xpath. Even [xpath works differently in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053632/is-xpath-is-different-for-different-browser), so if you want to run your code in all machine id selector is much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the *username* field as the element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.eltiempo.com/login")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.iframe-login")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("Nick Rondon@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.eltiempo.com/login')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='iframe-login']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("Nick Rondon@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: eltiempo]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)